# Unity3d lighmap issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, game-engine, lighting, graphicex

Im using unity 2017 and sometimes when i want to bake `lightmap` a dark shadow appear.

see image :
[image]

why this happening ?! it is progressive `lightmapper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution my self !

We have to set `Backface tolerance` to 0 in our scene `Lightmap parameter`.